# Efficiently remove strings that are contained within other strings in LinkedList

Tags: java, string, linked-list

I have a simple LinkedList that contains strings.

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("A, B, C, D");
list.add("R");
list.add("A");
list.add("C, D");
```

So, our LinkedList is: `[ "A, B, C, D", "R", "A" ,"C, D" ]`

As you can see, `"A"` and `"C, D"` are already contained in `"A,B,C,D"`.

What is the most efficient way to remove the contained strings?

Comment: Why not use a `Set`?

Comment: Set won't work, for that kind of logic you should write your own implementation.

Comment: Your data structure is impractical for the purpose. Consider storing the values as Set instead of CSV strings.

Comment: Why are you storing strings of a comma separated strings inside a list. What are you doing with these, that makes this the best representation?

Comment: What, **exactly**, should be the result? Should `"C, D"` simply be omitted? **Could** the string `"A, B, C, D"` be changed to `"A, B"` instead? And last but not least: What should happen when `"R, X"` should be added (with `R` already being present, but not `X`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use contains() method before adding new values (as long as you're adding single String every time, but you  are not...).

Second, it seems like this "problem" can be easily avoided, if you will change the way you're adding the strings, or the LinkedList restriction..

Anyway, this is a simple method that might suite your need:

```
private  void deleteIfContains(LinkedList<String> list, String str) {
    Iterator<String> headIterator = list.iterator();
    HashMap<Integer, String> newValues = new HashMap<>();
    int index = 0;

    while (headIterator.hasNext()) {
        String headString = headIterator.next();

        if (headString.contains(str)) {
            headIterator.remove();
            //replace method won't handle ','..you will need to use regex for it
            newValues.put(index, headString.replace(str, ""));
        }
        index++;
    }

    //Avoid ConcurrentModificationException
    for (int i : newValues.keySet()) {
        list.add(i, newValues.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a `Set` instead but you would have to contain every letter in a single `String` variable (maybe you should use `Character`?).

If you really want to stick to your own idea consider implementing your own `Set`. But first figure out what happens in that situation :

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("A, B, C, D");
list.add("C, E");
```

`C` should be rejected but what about `E`?

Comment: You comment that a `Set` wont work and proceed to answer the question saying use a `Set` ;)

Comment: Any existing set implementation won't work, as I stated in the comment a custom implementation could handle that logic.

Comment: You said, *I would suggest you use a Set instead* and then you said *If you really want to stick to your own idea*. You are basically saying use a `Set` right?

Comment: **but you would...**

Comment: So why don't you remove the paragraph that talks about a `Set` since you earlier said *Set won't work*? If `Set` won't work why even mention it?

Comment: Because I am suggesting a way to make it work with a `Set` which would make the code and logic more clear and clean.

Comment: I am confused. You are saying use a set and set wont work at the same time?

Comment: Dont' be. What i meant by _Set won't work_ is that existing `Set` implementations aren't ment for that kind of logic, but a custom implementation could do anything. Maybe my mental shortcut is not so clear for unexperienced programmers, I'm sorry for that. If you have any further questions write me a private message.

Comment: *Maybe my mental shortcut is not so clear for unexperienced programmers*. I can assure you that I am not an unepxerienced programmer. Note that you don't need a custom implementation of a `Set`. A basic of the shelf `Set` will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As @nikowis says the best solution depends on the problem definition.

If the values are the elements "A", "B", "C", "D", ... the more efficient solution (on computation time) can be to transform the list into a List> or a single Set.

If the values are "substring", for example "C, E" is ONE value (and not two "C" and "E") you can use a substring "Trie" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It can find very quickly the presence of the substring in the trie (O(log N) with N the length of the string to add).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the csv-format string to string values. Then store them as set element. If method `add()` returns true, that means value is already present.

```
String[] values = csvStr1.split(",");
Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(values));

String[] values2 = csvStr2.split(",");
for (String value: values2 ) {
    if( hashSet.add(value) == true ) {
          //value already present. Ignore this or do whatever you want.
    }
}
```